# How to reorganize photos along with sidecar files?

Tags: darktable

I'm using darktable 3.6.0 and am still struggling to find a good workflow. I originally started out with a folder structure where my photos were grouped by "event", but this proved limiting. Instead, I want to switch to a folder structure by date, like `yyyy/mm/dd/*.CR2`.

To use this new structure during import from camera, I'm using `gphoto2` from the command line:

```
gphoto2 --get-all-files --skip-existing --filename '%Y/%m/%d/%f.%C'
```

Subsequently I import the new photos into darktable. That all works fine.

**But how do I convert my existing library to this structure, while preserving the sidecar files (`*.XMP`) containing my edits and metadata?**

I tried to use the new `copy & import` feature in darktable, again with `$(YEAR)/$(MONTH)/$(DAY)` folder naming pattern, but this has two problems. One, sidecar files are not imported but instead created anew. And two, everything ends up in a folder with today's date.

Since `gphoto2` apparently knows how to read metadata, I tried to use it to import from a folder rather than a camera, but it doesn't seem to have an option for that. (Am I overlooking something?) But in any case, it would probably ignore sidecar files.

I could come up with a shell script using `exiftool` to read metadata and move files around accordingly, but surely there is a simpler way? In Lightroom this would have been trivial...

Answer (score 1):

Here's the shell script I came up with:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

in_dir=$1

for f in $(find $in_dir -iname \*.cr2 -or -iname \*.jpg | sort); do
  out_dir=$(exiftool -DateTimeOriginal $f | awk '{print $4}' | sed 's#:#/#g')
  mkdir -p $out_dir
  mv -v $f $out_dir/$(basename $f)
  mv -v $f.xmp $out_dir/$(basename $f).xmp || true
done

rmdir $in_dir
```

It's invoked one directory at a time, and will crash if it encounters anything unusual. It also doesn't work if there are spaces in any filename. So it's not great, but it solves my problem for now... better answers are still welcome, if not for me, then for the next person who comes along.

Comment: Will be wise to use double quotes around variables when do `mkdir` and `mv`. And for `xmp` file you use variable which is like `123456.cr2` and the result name will be `123456.cr2.xmp`

Comment: And about last command `rmdir` what will happen if you have subdirectories?

Comment: @RomeoNinov I know this is not production-ready code. I just let the script fail on such cases and dealt with them manually.

Comment: Thomas, it is always wise to follow some rules (and to have less errors to correct). BTW are the source files in one directory?

Comment: The reason for absence of quoting is that I like to put `echo` in front of all commands that have side effects, so that I can inspect what will be done. Once I'm satisfied I just pipe the output of the script through `sh`. That doesn't play nice with quotes unless you're very careful, so I just omitted them, knowing that I don't have spaces in filenames anyway. There were some cases with subdirectories in the source directory, but those are handled fine. Feel free to improve my answer or post one of your own based on this script.